# Write down the components of metric tensor correctly

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

this is a FLRW metric and I want to write down the metric tensor from this FLRW metric accurately. Can anyone please help me to do this? Thanks in advance. 
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ds^2 = a^2 ( \tau) [-(1+2 \Psi) d \tau^2 - 2 B_i d x^i \, d \tau + (1-2 \Phi ) \delta _{ij} d x^i d x^j + h_{ij} dx^i dx^j]. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: It's unclear from the question what has you stuck. We don't know whether you have basic problems with connecting a line element to components of a metric, or whether it's something more complicated about this particular example. Please clarify and let us know what your thoughts have been. One  issue would be to look out for double counting, e.g., $ds^2=dx dy$ has $g_{xy}=g_{yx}=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to calculate the scalar curvature Ricci tensor and the Christoffel symbol, that's why at first I need to write down the metric tensor properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy!
\begin{align}
g_{00} &= -\, a^2(\tau) (1 + 2 \Psi), \tag{1} \\[12pt]
g_{0i} &= -\, a^2(\tau)B_i, \tag{2} \\[12pt]
g_{ij} &=a^2(\tau)\big( (1 - 2 \Phi) \, \delta_{ij} + h_{ij} \big). \tag{3}
\end{align}
I'm puzzled why it wasn't obvious to you, though.

And this doesn't look like a FLRW metric.  Maybe it's for some unusual (non-comoving) coordinates system?

Comment: Geez, why the downvote?